# Can I decline a permanent position & extend my Probation?

Tags: probation

I will be completing my 6 months of Probation Period with my current employer shortly.

The Probation Period provides a couple of benefits that Permanent Position doesn't. Permanent position provides a lot more benefits but for the time being, I do care more about those couple of benefits.

So, is it possible for me to extend my Probation Period on request?

What would be the most polite way to do so?

Comment: I'm guessing this is probably more down to the companies policy. Check with HR. Not sure we could answer this. It is an odd request though.

Comment: Can you request an extension to your probation, there is nothing stopping you, of course the company also does not have to grant an extension either.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I'm guessing a far shorter notice period!

Comment: @Mike: Very True :P

Comment: "... and the alarm bells were ringing ..." :) You are going to have to come across as awful reassuring, if and when you make that request :) Having said that, you could let the probation period end without a murmur, collect your new benefits, and hit them with a two-week resignation  notice at any time if you so chose. Your company is probably more familiar and especially - comfortable, with this way of doing business than yours :) And comfort level matters a lot to a company hierarchy :)

Comment: The only benefit I have ever heard of that a probationary period provides, but a permanent position doesn't, is the ability to resign giving little notice. This is why asking to extend it will send alarm bells ringing in your company.

Comment: Note that some companies have strict limits on how long an internship/probationary/consulting position may be extended, to avoid giving the impression that they're abusing employees by not hiring them outright. This is very much a company-by-company issue. Having said that: Be aware that extending a probationary period also provides another window -- and some incentive -- for the company to decide not to make you permanent. If we can figure out that you're after the shorter notice period, so can your manager and HR, and they're going to start looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So, is it possible for me to extend my Probation Period on request?

Anything is possible, although I have never heard of anyone asking to stay on probation - never mind being granted such a request.

Probationary periods are intended to be the time where both sides get to know each other, and decide if there is a good fit.

At the end of the period, deciding that it isn't a good fit is easy, and departure is quick.

If the "benefit" you are seeking by staying on the probationary period is the ability to depart quickly, it seems unlikely that a company wanting a permanent employee would be willing to extend. Why should they bother when you are giving signals that you won't be around very long? The better move from the company point of view is to part ways and quickly bring in another candidate to start their probationary period in hopes that she/he will stick around.

I usually don't offer probationary periods when I hire. The few times I have, I wouldn't have extended the worker if they asked for a probation period extension.

> What would be the most polite way to do so?

As with most things, the best choice is to communicate with the people that matter, and are in a position to act on what you want.

Go to your manager and politely ask about the possibility of extending your probation. Be prepared with an explanation when you are inevitably asked "Why would you want to do that?" Be prepared if the answer is "No."

An alternative would be for you to ask for a different status.

You could offer to remain as a "temporary" employee, perhaps until a new permanent candidate is found. That way, you could retain your easy-out "benefit", but still provide value to the company.

It doesn't sound as if you really want to be on Probation any longer. You just want one (or some) of the things that go along with being on Probation. Talk to your manager, and be clear about what you really want. It seldom hurts to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly request to stay on probation. It's extremely rare and results may vary. Like all matters of this nature clear communication is really the best approach.

Based on your response a more appropriate action might be to negotiate that whatever benefits the probationary period offers to be added to your permanent position. Odds are if a probationary position is offering a benefit that a permanent position is not it's probably just an oversight. (Barring if it's a benefit of being able to quit without notice or similar, if that's the benefit you're hoping to keep than perhaps taking another job is in order as that would imply you're already considering quitting before you're even settled in)